# Using rolling time period window calculations on a groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

This is my current Dataframe, csv file sorted by login time, and then reset_index

```
    Login Time          User    Port
0   2019-10-19 22:00:05 Jane    22
1   2019-10-19 22:00:05 Jane    22
2   2019-10-19 22:02:30 John    22
3   2019-10-19 22:02:44 John    22
4   2019-10-19 22:02:54 John    22
5   2019-10-19 22:03:59 Mary    22
6   2019-10-19 22:04:12 John    22
7   2019-10-19 22:04:17 John    22
8   2019-10-19 22:04:42 Kathy   22
9   2019-10-19 22:04:42 Kathy   22
```

What i want, is a separate column counting how many times the user had logged in for the last 30seconds, like this:

```
    Login Time          User    Port    LastLogin30Sec
0   2019-10-19 22:00:05 Jane    22      1
1   2019-10-19 22:00:05 Jane    22      2
2   2019-10-19 22:02:30 John    22      1
3   2019-10-19 22:02:44 John    22      2
4   2019-10-19 22:02:54 John    22      3
5   2019-10-19 22:03:59 Mary    22      1
6   2019-10-19 22:04:12 John    22      1
7   2019-10-19 22:04:17 John    22      2
8   2019-10-19 22:04:42 Kathy   22      1
9   2019-10-19 22:04:42 Kathy   22      2
```

So i decided to use rolling to specify the time period and count the rows. Rolling with a time period needs DateTime to be indexed

```
df = df.set_index("Login Time")
df[df["User"]=="John"]["Port"].rolling("30s").count()

Login Time
2019-10-19 22:02:30    1.0
2019-10-19 22:02:44    2.0
2019-10-19 22:02:54    3.0
2019-10-19 22:04:12    1.0
2019-10-19 22:04:17    2.0
Name: Port, dtype: float64
```

Okay that code works. But i would like to do this for every user, so i decided to leverage on groupby...and this is where is hit a stumbling block.

Because rolling by time period needs a datetime index, i have to preserve the index in groupby. But the index in non-unique

```
df["Count"] = df.groupby(["User"], as_index=False)['Port'].rolling("30s").count()
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

So i figured, i might as well dont set the time index in the first place, and set it after the groupby operation....but you can't set_index on a groupbydataframe

```
df["Count"] = df.groupby(["User"], as_index=False).set_index("Login Time")["Port"].rolling("30s").count()
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'set_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

And i dont see how apply would work for me.

Is anyone able to advise further? The whole problem seems to center around .rolling time window needs a datetimeindex rather than just a datetime series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply function in which you can perform your rolling function for each group

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:00:05'), 'Jane', '22'], [1, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:00:05'), 'Jane', '22'], [2, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:02:30'), 'John', '22'], [3, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:02:44'), 'John', '22'], [4, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:02:54'), 'John', '22'], [5, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:03:59'), 'Mary', '22'], [6, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:04:12'), 'John', '22'], [7, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:04:17'), 'John', '22'], [8, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:04:42'), 'Kathy', '22'], [9, pd.Timestamp('2019-10-19 22:04:42'), 'Kathy', '22']], columns=('id', 'Login-Time', 'User', 'Port'))

df2 = df.groupby("User").apply(lambda g: g.set_index("Login-Time")["Port"].rolling("30s").count()).reset_index()
print(df2)
```

**Result**

```py
 User          Login-Time  Port
0   Jane 2019-10-19 22:00:05   1.0
1   Jane 2019-10-19 22:00:05   2.0
2   John 2019-10-19 22:02:30   1.0
3   John 2019-10-19 22:02:44   2.0
4   John 2019-10-19 22:02:54   3.0
5   John 2019-10-19 22:04:12   1.0
6   John 2019-10-19 22:04:17   2.0
7  Kathy 2019-10-19 22:04:42   1.0
8  Kathy 2019-10-19 22:04:42   2.0
9   Mary 2019-10-19 22:03:59   1.0
```

Comment: Well i was trying to avoid binning into 30seconds interval, as it doesnt count 29s, 44s, 54s in the same bin